# Does such homomorphism exist?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

$G$ is a group: $|G|=20$.

Is there such a group G, for which the homomorphism $\tau :G-->Z_{10}$ exist?$$$$
The same question for: $\tau :G-->Z_{15}$

$$$$

I think that I should use here the fact $o\left(\tau \left(g\right)\right)| o\left(g\right)$

What I know is:
In $Z_{10}$ the order of it's elements is: 1,2,5,10, and in $G$ the order of it's elements can be (1,2,4,5,10,20).

And $\tau$ is homomorphism so: $\tau \left(g_1g_2\right)=\tau \left(g_1\right)+\tau \left(g_2\right)\left(modn\right)$

Now, from here how do I correlate between the fact about the order and the formula of homomorphism, I can try to find a group like that manually trying to find each element and build such a group (or fail bulding it), but it is hard work and not so smart defintly.

Comment: What's $\tau$?  Can't you just take the trivial morphism?

Comment: What kind of homomorphism are you looking for? I am asking, because there is always the trivial homomorphism mapping all group elements to the identity element. Or do you want your homomorphisms to be surjective?

Comment: It doesn't said anything about it in the question eather, but let's try to find non trivial. 
And we are free in choosing our group eather, because the question goes like "Is there such group for which there is such homomorphism?"
So if we find any group of order 20 and any non-trivial homomorphism, the answer is yes. 
I mean ii doesnt must be true (the existence of such homomophism) for each group of order 20, but just for one we can find. (I dont know, maybe for one group of order 20 such homo' exists and for other it doesn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suppose that you want a surjective homomorphism or the answer is trivial.

For the first question you just can choose $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

For the second answer you can't have a surjective homomorphism because 15 doesn't divide 20, but you know that $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ contains a subgroup of order five so you can still have a non trivial morphism by choosing 
$$G=\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$$

Comment: I don't understand so much the cross symbol in that context. Can you write such homomorphism in himself from group of order 20 to $Z_{15}$ ?

Comment: The cross symbol is the direct product. The direct product $A \times B$ is defined to be the set $\left\lbrace (a,b)| a\in A \\ b\in B\right \rbrace$ and is a grouo with the multiplication defined $$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,bd)$$.

Comment: You can prove that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$ is isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$. From this if $x$ is an element in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ with order 5 you can define a map $f(1)=x$

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I'm looking for a group and a homomorphism (not a group that ismorphic to another), a function, from G (of order 20) to $Z_{15}$.
O r maybe I didnt understand your though clear. Ok, so this cross defined is isomorphic, agree. But what is the function itself. Maybe you didnt finish your writings.

Comment: In my last comment i defined a non-trivial function betwen $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$